# postgres relation with OID does not exist

Tags: postgresql

Trying to upgrade postgres 11 to postgres 14. I am facing this problem. for which I am posting this question.
I am observing following error.

```
*pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  relation with OID 323191 does not exist
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE "schema"."table_name" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE*
```

I have gone through various forums and questions but dint find same issue as mine. I have also tried following queries to find if I can fetenter code herech that oid.

but all the below table output shows 0 rows.

```
*select * from pg_type where typnamespace=323191;
select * from pg_class where relnamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_operator where oprnamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_conversion where connamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_opclass where opcnamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_aggregate where aggfnoid = 323191 or aggtransfn  = 323191 or aggfinalfn = 323191;
select * from pg_proc where pronamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_proc where pronamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_class where relnamespace = 323191;
select * from pg_depend where relnamespace = 323191 or oid=323191;*
```

I appreciate any advise which help to resolve this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) *...relation with OID 323191 does not exist* means what it says that `323191` does not exist. Searching for it is just going to prove that. 2) In the database look for the actual table that the alias `"schema"."table_name"` refers to. Does that exist?

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver  I tried searching on google about this errr and I can see all above select queries to check if it exist. , for your suggestion alias,  I dont have much idea on postgres alias for table.  I have tried to search on google but its redirecting me to column alias and table alias in query..  do you have query which can confirm the reference of alias to this table? thanks in advance.                                                                 -> also  one info. that the actual table "schema"."table_name", I can select this table any row. I can also get count of this table.

Comment: What I am saying is that  `"schema"."table_name"` is not the actual table name, you just created that for the question.  So, look for the actual table in the database.

Comment: in our env "schema"."table_name" actual data is user3.app_customers

I can select that entire table select * from user3.app_customers; and it doesnt throw any error. I can fully extract output into flat file as well with following.

psql -U user3 -h localhost -d stage -c "select * from user3.app_customers" > outfile

this has (29578 rows) and 55MB of size

Comment: 1) **Add information as updates to the question, not in the comments**. 2) Using the Postgres 14 version of `pg_dump` what happens if you do `pg_dump -U user3 -h localhost -d stage -t user3.app_customers -f user3.app_customers.sql`? 3) What is the complete upgrade command you are using?